# text positioning in one line

Tags: html, css

I want to text be in one line like this:

[image]

but I don't know how to do it. It looks like this:

[image: image2]

[link to the code](https://codepen.io/Exclusive_Dosser/pen/yLzWNGq)

```css
.clients_container {
  width: 1310px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 5.75rem;
}

.clients_title {
  margin-top: 2.85rem;
  margin-bottom: 3.65rem;
  font-size: 2.75rem;
}

.clients_items {
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 3rem;
}

.clients_item_inside {
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  gap: 1rem;
  width: 316px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.clients_item_inside,
.aspect_ratio {
  max-width: 17rem;
}

.aspect_ratio {
  position: relative;
  height: 191px;
}

.clients_item_title {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<section class="clients_section font_ubuntu background_lightblue">
  <div class="cont mr_auto">
    <div class="clients_container mr_auto">
      <h2 class="clients_title fontweight_bold text_center">
        Co mówią o nas klienci:
      </h2>
      <div class="clients_items">
        <div class="clients_item_inside ">
          <div class="aspect_ratio">
            <img src="../img/Karolina_Skulska_-1.png">
          </div>
          <span class="text_center fontweight_regular"></span>
          <h4 class="clients_item_title margin_reset fontweight_bold relative text_center">
            90% WRACA NA KOLEJNE SZKOLENIE
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="clients_item_inside ">
          <div class="aspect_ratio">
            <img src="../img/Karolina_Skulska_-1.png">
          </div>
          <span class="text_center fontweight_regular"></span>
          <h4 class="clients_item_title margin_reset fontweight_bold relative text_center">
            97% ZAUWAŻA ZDECYDOWANE ZMNIEJSZENIE STRESU ZAWODOWEGO I W ŻYCIU PRYWATNYM
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="clients_item_inside ">
          <div class="aspect_ratio">
            <img src="../img/Karolina_Skulska_-1.png">
          </div>
          <span class="text_center fontweight_regular"></span>
          <h4 class="clients_item_title margin_reset fontweight_bold relative text_center">
            99% POLECA NASZE USŁUGI I DZIELI SIĘ TECHNIKAMI Z BLISKI I PRZYJACIÓŁMI
          </h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+align+text+top+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Share your implemented code

Comment: Please use the snippet editor to include the code in the question itself, rather than an external link. (See the useful [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) link in mplunjans comment for a guide)

Comment: reduce your font size don't use align-item, text-align:center; would be enough.

Answer (score 1):

In CSS file add following properties to the class `.clients_items`

```
align-items: flex-start;
text-align: center;
```

the style class `.clients_items` should look like this

```
.clients_items {
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 3rem;
  align-items: flex-start; //new
  text-align: center; //new
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider not to use `grid` in `.clients_item_inside`.

```
.clients_item_inside {
    width: 316px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

[Here is the example](https://codepen.io/guswnsxodlf/pen/wvrbKWm).